# C programming language, shortest path

Tags: c, algorithm, shortest-path

I'm am writing a code to find the shortest distance between two points. My code is working perfect till now. I mean it finds the distance and the path that they should pass. I need to print this information, but I should make a print function. The way it works is something like that: For example initial point is 4 and final is 13.

I should come up with an algorithm that check their intermediate points. Let's say between 4 & 13 there is point : 7

4--7--13   Now I need to check every point between them like:

4--6--7--9--13 To be more specific it will check if there is a point between 4-6 and 6-7 and 7-9 and 9-13. So next in the next iteration it may be formed another list like:

4--2--6--7--5--9--17--13  Now let's say that there will not be any intermediate value between them. And that is what I should print. I really would appreciate any help, suggestion that you may give to me

Comment: Use recursion to build the list of points, and print it when the recursion returned. Anyway, is this homework?

Comment: but how should I use recursion? NO it is not an homework

Comment: How are you storing your points?  If your points lend themselves to being stored in a graph structure (most point systems basically fall into a graph structure), one of the best ways to solve this problem is with graphing algorithms.

Comment: Which algorithm do you use? Dijkstra?

Comment: Are you representing (or could you) the points in your program as nodes in a Graph data structure? Using a graph you could implement the [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm and get the min distance between all the Graph nodes

Comment: I did use Floyd-Warshall algorithm but I do not need the single distance. I mean I want to find the whole path

Comment: Yes, Dijkstra as that is the most efficient SSSP (single source shortest path) algorithm. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm . Floyd-Warshall will work fine except that it is slower than Dijkstra's.  Dijkstra O(e+vlgv) where as floyd-warshall is o(v^3).  Dijkstra much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Warshall-Floyd algorithm (used by the OP), has a version which is able to determine the path in addition to the distance between nodes of a graph:

[Floyd-Warshall algorithm with path-reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction)

However, it must be noted that this is not the best possible algorithm to solve the [shortest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSP).

Comment: Dijkstra much faster.  It has path reconstruction as well and in my opinion is much easier because path reconstruction is built into the functionality.  Floyd-Warshall very slow expecially for large graphs. Check wiki  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Well as far as I am concerned O(V^3) is a terrible run time.  O(E+V lg V) much better.  Floyd Warshall is terrible recommendation especially when path reconstruction is required.

Comment: yeah you are right, but is much harder to implement it I think

Comment: @NKamrath You are absolutely right. But the OP uses FW, and needed only a technique to find the path, in addition to the distance. Anyway, thanks for the -1. Peace :)

Comment: If you knew what you were talking about I wouldn't neg you.  As you are wrong I am forced to.  SSSP is what was asked for not ASSP which is what you supplied which gives the person you "helped" an algorithm which will run for much longer to compute the same thing and then require him to put in extra effort to reconstruct the path instead of iterating a set of pointers in nodes on a graph.  Hope you don't steer anyone else that wrong.

Comment: @NKamrath OK, I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm pretty sure I'm obsessive compulsive about algorithms.  I blame my professors they have ruined my life haha.  -1 removed +1 added

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like recursion would be the best way to do this. If it already can find the shortest path, im assuming you have a function written to find the shortest path between 2 points. Maybe you could recursively break down the list, find the shortest path and append that point to a list.

Edit, sorry i misread your question, you need to find the midpoint. Pass a recursive function the whole list of points and find a midpoint. If one exists, add it to a list. If there is no midpoint dont append anything. Continue calling this function until you come to the base case, which should be 1 or 2 points in the list

Comment: yeah you may be right, if I use an array to store the elements how should I proceed to update it?

Comment: I would think that you can find the midpoint at position n/2. Then break the list into 2 parts from 1 to n/2 and n/2 to n. If the list has an even number of elements, break it into 2 lists from 1 to n/2 - 1 and n/2 + 1 to n and dont append a midpoint to the list. Then call the recursive function on both lists. To update, you need to put the midpoint in the right spot. This might be able to be done by keeping track of the where you are in the list. Let me think about this for a second

Comment: I think it is a bit tricky, because if I find a midpoint, the list should be shifted.Secondly how will the next iteration work, I mean will it take the old values or take the updated one? I think that there may be values that will be ignored by next iteration

Comment: element is right divide n/2 take the result and make two lists.  n = num elements in the list.  subList1 = elements 0 to n; sublist2 = elements n+1 to n.  Then recursively break those lists using the same function.  When there is less 2 or fewer elements left in the list start adding those to a list of intermediate points.  you have to make sure you call the recursion on the first part then the second in order to get a correctly ordered solution.  The solution list should be returned and appended to at each level until the recursion finishes